# error 403 when scraping Hansard which uses Cloudflare

Tags: web-scraping, cloudflare, http-status-code-403

I am trying to extract a graph from [this link](https://hansard.parliament.uk/search?searchTerm=immigration&partial=False). I need to write a loop to extractd the info of graphs like this for a set of specific criteria. Using Developers tools >> Network, I found [the URL](https://hansard.parliament.uk/timeline/query?searchTerm=immigration&startDate=27%2F04%2F2017&endDate=27%2F04%2F2022&house=0&contributionType=&isDebatesSearch=False&memberId=) to the data underlying this graph. The data seems to be stored in XML format.

I have tried different approaches, but I keep getting 403 Error. It doesn't matter whether I want to extract just the plot or make a get request for the whole web page. I think the problem is that Cloudflare kicks in. Any idea how I might be able to get around this? Any help is very much appriciated.

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://hansard.parliament.uk/timeline/query?searchTerm=immigration&startDate=27%2F04%2F2017&endDate=27%2F04%2F2022&house=0&contributionType=&isDebatesSearch=False&memberId='

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'}

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/  ? Python examples: `https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=cloudscraper [python]`

Comment: @QHarr I have tried it. To my surprise, it worked once but won't now.